# Unable to start server due following issues: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
**Version:** Kepler Release
glassfish version 3.1.2.2

Unable to start server due following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassfishGenericServerBehaviour$StartJob.call(GlassfishGenericServerBehaviour.java:659)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassfishGenericServerBehaviour$StartJob.call(GlassfishGenericServerBehaviour.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

glassfish server stant alon work fine but cant start in eclipse
glassfish 4 same as

Comment: Is there a more complete stack trace?  Thread.run() suggests that this isn't the main thread and that it's not actually stopping Glassfish.

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem. What i did was adding following `-Duser.language=en` line after **-vmargs** parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7:
Run eclipse using "Run as administrator"